# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute Latitude

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can someone please explain to me, why when I write like this everything works fine:

```
def create_geo_hash(lat, lon):
    latitude = float(lat)
    longitude = float(lon)
    geo_hash = pygeohash.encode(latitude, longitude, precision=4)
    return geo_hash


def fill_with_valid_coords(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    validated_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: check_for_invalid_coords(row))
    geo_hash_rdd = validated_rdd.map(lambda row: (create_geo_hash(row[5], row[6]), ))
    geo_hash_df = geo_hash_rdd.toDF(schema=['Geo_Hash'])
    return geo_hash_df
```

But when I pass the entire row to the mapping function like this:

```
geo_hash_rdd = validated_rdd.map(lambda row: create_geo_hash(row))
```

and change my `create_geo_hash` function accordingly:

```
def create_geo_hash(row):
    latitude = float(row.Latitude)
    longitude = float(row.Longitude)
    geo_hash = pygeohash.encode(latitude, longitude, precision=4)
    return geo_hash
```

I am having `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Latitude'`

When I pass entire row to the `validated_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: check_for_invalid_coords(row))` and then use it in another function as a row it works fine.

Comment: Your working code accesses `row[5]` and `row[6]`. Your non-working code accesses `row.Latitude` and `row.Longitude`. Why the change?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Hello! I am sorry but I am afraid I don't understand the question. All I wanted to do is to use the same mapping function but pass only one argument `row`, not two arguments.